# pybbg: extracting data from Bloomberg using ISIN codes, not tickers

Tags: bloomberg

I have a large list of ISIN codes and would like to use them to pull Bloomberg data into Python using pybbg.

for example, this gives me nan values for all ISIN codes:

```
fld_list = ['OAS_SPREAD_MID','DUR_ADJ_MID','DUR_ADJ_OAS_MID']
bb = bbg.bdp("US46628LAA61 ISIN", fld_list)
```

When using the tickers, I get all field values.

Any ideas would be really appreciated.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax to request data for an ISIN is `/isin/US46628LAA61`.

Answer (score 1):

With [`xbbg`](https://xbbg.readthedocs.io/) you can do this:

```
In[1]: from xbbg import blp

In[2]: fld_list = ['OAS_SPREAD_MID','DUR_ADJ_MID','DUR_ADJ_OAS_MID']
In[3]: blp.bdp(['US46628LAA61 Mtge', 'US46631JAA60 Mtge'], fld_list)

Out[3]:
              ticker            field  value
0  US46628LAA61 Mtge   OAS_SPREAD_MID  -5.30
1  US46628LAA61 Mtge      DUR_ADJ_MID   6.00
2  US46628LAA61 Mtge  DUR_ADJ_OAS_MID   2.43
3  US46631JAA60 Mtge   OAS_SPREAD_MID  50.10
4  US46631JAA60 Mtge      DUR_ADJ_MID   1.71
5  US46631JAA60 Mtge  DUR_ADJ_OAS_MID   4.09
```